# Images not found in drawable-large nor drawable-small

Tags: android

I have some images in `drawable-normal` I can load them via

```
 Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), resourceId,
             mBitmapFactoryOptions)
```

When I move the images over to `drawable-large` (and remove them from `drawable-normal`), then the images are not loaded anymore. There is no error, I just get `null` for `bm`. When I move them to `drawable-hdpi` or the like, they are loaded again.

Does Android handle the -small, -normal and -large folders different from the other resource folders? As described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch), it should eventually load the images from the -large folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I found the answer to my own question. Reading the aforementioned page more carefully, it turns out, that Android only searches the `drawable-*dpi` folders automatically, for all other qualifiers it only looks in the default folder if it does not find the resource in the more specific one.
In other words, if it does not find the resource in `drawable-normal`, it looks in `drawable` and then stops trying. It's only for the `drawable-*dpi` folders that android looks into all those folders. I guess I'll switch to these. Thanks to Tanmay for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen any `drawable-large` folder in your given [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch) .

Android only supports `drawable-ldpi`,`drawable-mdpi` ,`drawable-hdpi` and `drawable` for storing `drawable` objects.

Comment: Table 2 on that page shows for the qualifier "Screen size" the possible values small, normal, large, xlarge.

Comment: That uses in `AndroidManifest.xml` to tell that wheather the application will be used for those screens  **example**   `<supports-screens
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true"
></supports-screens>`

Comment: Yeah, I have that line in my Manifest file, but it doesn't help :-/

Comment: then why are you creating the `drawable-normal` instead of creating `drawable-mdpi`?